# Updating datetime field from Visualforce remoteObjects

Tags: visualforce, datetime, remote-objects

I m trying to update a datetime field from VF page using remoteObjets and I am getting this error:

> err: Error: Last Viewed Timestamp: value not of required type:
>   2019-11-20T11:00:56.373Z

This is my relevant code:

```
var myDate = new Date().toISOString();
var record = new $M.Form_Details__c({Id:'{!myID}',Last_Viewed_Timestamp__c:myDate
});
record.update(updateCallback);
```

What should be the right datetime format for the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be a normal Date:

```
var rightNow = new Date();
var record = new $M.Form_Details__c({Id='{!myId}',Last_Viewed_Timestamp__c:rightNow});
```

The Remote Objects framework automatically converts the value to the correct type for you.